# PHP: Illegal string offset - But it is an array and the key exists

Tags: php

there are so many posts to "illegal string offset" but i didnt find any solution. Maybe someone have a look at my code:

```
function neue($pv){                    <== LINE 365
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($pv);
    echo "</pre>";
    if (is_array($pv)){
        echo "IS ARRAY";
    }
    if (strlen($pv["Speichern"])>0){   <== LINE 372
        save();
    }
}
```

This is only a snippet but it shows the relevant part.
$pv is an array the output of print_r is:

```
Array (
    [bez] => Test
    [gruppe] => 0
    [MoAnf] => 11:00
    [MoEnd] => 12:00
    [Speichern] => Speichern
    [PHPSESSID] => d356016bf4c5c5b5758f526ba4e4108e
    [setid] =>  
)
```

I check if it is an arry and the output is:

> IS ARRAY

So why this line:

```
if (strlen($pv["Speichern"])>0){
```

throws:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'Speichern' in
>   /webseiten/save.php on line
>   372

EDIT:

This is line 372:

```
if (strlen($pv["Speichern"])>0){
```

i have printed out the array $pv before and i have checked it is an array.  There are no other lines between the function call and the error line. i have posted all code lines.

EDIT:

The result of var_dump($pv["Speichern"]); is:

> string(9) "Speichern"

EDIT FOUND PROBLEM:

I found the problem. The variable setid was not set.

```
[setid] =>
```

If i change my code to:

```
function neue($pv){                    
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($pv);
    echo "</pre>";
    if (is_array($pv)){
        echo "IS ARRAY";
    }
    $pv["setid"] = "foobar";
    if (strlen($pv["Speichern"])>0){   
        save();
    }
}
```

The code runs without any exception. But why this results in an error for "Speichern" i dont know. Maybe a bug in PHP?

Comment: What is the code in `/webseiten/save.php on line 372`? You probably don't have `$pv["Speichern"]` defined. Try to print out `$pv` array.

Comment: This shoud work. Are you sure you defined `$pv["Speichern" ]` ? Because your code seems to be correct.

Comment: As you can see in the print_r result "Speichern" is defined in the array

Comment: `$pv` is a string. With that code that would never happen. Post an MCVE, and look for silly things (are you editing the right file?).

Comment: sounds obvious but what does `var_dump($pv["Speichern"]);` give you. And also try replacing your double quotes with single quotes, it probably won't make a change, but maybe...

Answer (score 0):

The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays. foreach works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an uninitialized variable. There are two syntaxes:

```
foreach (array_expression as $value)
    statement
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

Try this.

```
  function neue($pv){                    //<== LINE 365
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($pv);
        echo "</pre>";
        if (is_array($pv)){
            echo "IS ARRAY";
        }
     foreach($pv as $pv){
        if (strlen($pv["Speichern"])>0){   //<== LINE 372
            save();
        }
      }
    }
```